# Reply times vary with ping test

Tags: ping

I am seeing the following and I have already scanned all the computers for viruses and there were some but they have been removed.  Would anyone have any other ideas on what tools or other things that could be done to fix this?

```
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=45ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=40ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=46ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=43ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=60ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=51ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=44ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=55ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=48ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.20.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
```

Comment: Are you on a wireless/wifi connection or is it a LAN connection?

Comment: What is the problem?  The ping times you're seeing are variable but well within the normal range.  Perhaps your switch is just busy, or the target computer is sending traffic at the time.

Answer (score 1):

If the machine you are pinging from is on wireless, this kind of fluctuation is perfectly normal. If you are on a wired network, this does seem somewhat odd, but could be the result of other traffic on your network or the router you are pinging being busy handling other traffic.

Comment: I am pinging the router from a computer that is hard wired into the network.  THis also happens when I ping other devices on the network.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior with other devices, or just this computer?

Comment: I actually just saw that bad of response times pinging the router.  I just tried pinging the server and other devices and it looks normal so I guess this was a false alarm.  Thanks for the quick responses though.